# How to definte variables for fields without data in them?

Tags: php, wordpress, runtime-error, call

I've got a number of calls to data in a WordPress site using a number of custom fields. The fields aren't required to fill out on the back end. So in my templates, I have calls like this:

```
<?php if( $additional_fields[ 'Time' ] ) { echo 'Duration: ' . $additional_fields[ 'Time' ] . '<br>'; } ?>
```

Now this does work. Which is great. But if I turn on WP Debug, and there's no data for this field, I get greeted by the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: Time in /home/hellod8/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/page-data.php on line 63

Now again, not mission critical. If I turn debugging off, the problem goes away. However, I'd still like to solve this.

I thought I could do this above the call to the function:

```
<?php $additional_fields[ 'Time' ] = ''; ?>
```

But all that does is not display anything at all for that field.

So what would work to eliminate the error?

Comment: Check with php function ```isset``` if "time" is present in your array.

Comment: `if( isset($additional_fields['Time'])) {..` _or_ `if(!empty($additional_fields['Time'])) {..` - The first one checks if there is a field called 'Time', the second one additionally checks if there's a value (other than '') inside.

Answer (score 2):

You an use `isset()` to determine if the variable is set. Example:

```
if( isset($additional_fields['Time']) ){
    echo $additional_fields['Time'];
}
```

If you're looking to see if the variable is set and not empty, you can use `empty()`. Example:

```
if( !empty($additional_fields['Time']) ){
    echo $additional_fields['Time'];
}
```

`empty()` will check for a myriad of things like whether the variable `isset`, or the value is `blank`, `zero`, `false`, or `null`. `empty()` is slightly slower than `isset()` (primarly because of these additional checks).

Empty would be the same as saying:

```
if( isset($additional_fields['Time']) && $additional_fields['Time'] ){
    echo $additional_fields['Time'];
}
```

`isset()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

`empty()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php